# Can `oc create` behave in a "transactional"/"atomic" manner when asked to create _multiple_ objects on the cluster?

Tags: deployment, transactions, openshift, okd

I have written a number of related OKD object definitions, each in its own YAML file. These together essentially make up an application deployment. I am doing something like the following to install my application on an OKD cluster, which works to my satisfaction when *none of the objects already exist [on the cluster]*:

```
oc create -f deploymentconfig.yaml,service.yaml,route.yaml,configmap.yaml,secret.yaml
```

However, if some of the objects `oc create` is asked to create, already exist on the cluster, then `oc create` refuses to re-create them (naturally) but it *will have created* all the other ones that did not exist.

This isn't ideal when the objects I am creating on the cluster were made to behave "in tandem", and are parts of an application where they depend on one another -- the configuration map, for instance, is pretty much a hard requirement as without it the container will fail to start properly (lacking configuration data through a mounted volume).

I'd like to know, can `oc create` be made to behave like either *all* of the objects specified on the command line, are installed, or *none* if *some* of them already exist or if there were errors?

I am aware OKD has template faculties and other features that may greatly help with application deployment, so if I am putting too much (misplaced) faith on `oc create` here, I'll take an alternative solution if `oc create` by design does not do "transactions". This is just me trying what seems simple from where I currently stand -- not being much of an OKD expert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no such thing.

In Kubernetes (and so in Openshift), manifests are declarative and idempotent in the most of scenarios. Each `kind` can be modified in atomic way, but not a group of resources all together.

You can `oc apply` or `oc replace` to create or modify some resource in a atomic way, but the same cannot be done with a lot of resources because Kubernetes don't see them as a unity.

Even if you have a `Template` or a `List`, some resources may have problems and you will end with a part of the whole.

For this kind of thing `helm` is much more versatile and works as you want with `--atomic` flag.

If you have all your manifests separated, you can achieve a similar effect with:

```
oc apply -f dirwithmanifests/
```

Comment: Thank you, Hector. What do you mean, in this context, with "manifests are declarative"? Declarative nature of say, a manifest, does not per se forbid e.g. transactional nature of some mechanism processing it, does it? Is it the rather the fact they're declarative by _resource_ that precludes transactions?

Comment: Hum... yeah, looks confusing reading now. With `declarative` I mean what you `create/replace` or `apply`  should always present the same result, like idempotent things, no relation with transactions. I over thought.

Comment: A simple `oc apply` is not enough for you?

Comment: Apologies for never answering, Hector. I have since come to a much better understanding of the idea behind e.g. a _deployment configuration_, which helped dispel the original cause of my question. I have understood that I was looking for transactional or "atomic" behaviour in the wrong place. To put it another way, indeed `oc apply` is, as of late, quite enough for me :)